# How to get previous url and it's parameters in PHP

Tags: php

we all knew to get previous URL by

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

is there any way to get previous URL parameters if the URL has been override?

Example:

point at: `https:example.com/kids-logo-grip.html`

then go to: `https:example.com/t-shirt.html` => At this point, i wish to get all parameters of previous URL (https:example.com/kids-logo-grip.html).

Comment: What URL parameters? If the `HTTP_REFERER` is set (which is not guaranteed so never rely on it), it should contain the full URL from the referrer. What exactly is it you want to get and where are you stuck?

Comment: https:example.com/kids-logo-grip.html => this has been overrided by .htaccess, raw url is https:example.com/productview/id/1. So i wish to get id value (it is 1). Is it understandable?

Comment: If you want to store the _internal_ URL htaccess rewrites _to_, then you need to store that yourself somehow (like in a session or something). The `HTTP_REFERER` is set by the client and the client doesn't have any clue about the rewrites. And the server just sees two separate requests and doesn't have any clue what page it came from.

Comment: so it is not able to handle?

Comment: Not out-of-the-box, no. You could probably build some history log in the user session for it though so it can be handled.

Comment: @M.Eriksson thank you for explanation and solution. Please log your answer so i can mark it as a best answer.